# What Happens to Redirects if Product Deleted in Magento

Tags: redirect, seo, delete

I have 10's of thousands of disabled products on my site (inherited from previous owner) that I will never use again.

There are redirects set up on most of them already, but I want to delete them as it is annoying to maintain the catalog with so much irrelevant product in the back end, not to mention the possible performance pickup from getting rid of them.

Does anyone know if my redirects will be affected if I delete a product? Will this cause more problems than it is worth?

Answer (score 0):

It Will not affect your redirection because I have done same thing in my website.
In my site we always make promotion base products and after sale ends we delete those products from the website and redirect those products on specific urls.

For exp: Suppose my deleted product url is `www.yoursite.com/product-1`

Then I have added 301 in `.htaccess` like: `Redirect 301 /product-1 www.yoursite.com/product-2`

Then if some one try to access this url your `.htaccess` redirect it on pointed url